# Deriving what $\cos(A+2B)$ is

Tags: trigonometry

We know that $\cos(A+B) = \cos(A)\cos(B) - \sin(A)\sin(B)$ , but I don't understand with the $2B$. Would it just become $\cos(A+2B) = \cos(A)\cos(2B) - \sin(A)\sin(2B)$?

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: "...would it just become...?" **Yes, exactly**.  If desired, you can convert this into an expression involving trig functions around $B$ instead of $(2B)$, by simply further refining your expression via the corresponding formulas for $\cos(2B)$, and $\sin(2B).$

Comment: There is nothing special about certain combinations of letters and numbers.
$$\cos(\square+\circ) = \cos(\square)\cos(\circ) - \sin(\square)\sin(\circ)$$

Answer (score 3):

Further expansion is possible with repeated use of the angle addition identities.
$$\begin{align}
\cos (a + 2b) &= \cos a \cos 2b - \sin a \sin 2b \\
&= \cos a (\cos b \cos b - \sin b \sin b) - \sin a (\sin b \cos b + \cos b \sin b) \\
&= \cos a (\cos^2 b - \sin^2 b) - \sin a (2 \sin b \cos b) \\
&= \cos a \cos^2 b - \cos a \sin^2 b - 2 \sin a \sin b \cos b.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, exactly! Just think of $2b=c$ and then substitute it back.

EDIT: It was marked that this not an answer, a requirement for substitution in general is that it has to be bijective, and indeed $2b=c$ is bijective.

Now you can use the formula $\cos(A+C) = \cos A\cos C - \sin A\sin C$
where $C=2B$ now you have it. Note that $\cos(2a)=\cos^2a-\sin^2(a)$. YoOu could use this as well later on.

Comment: This is by no way an answer!

Comment: Whats wrong about it ?

Comment: I think it's a perfectly fine answer I didn't even think about it that way !

Comment: However, then you wouldn't be able to apply the double angle formulas which is a problem when it comes to simplification.

Comment: You do not bring any new information, only confirmed what was written in the original post.

Comment: substitution was basically the answer

Comment: Your first, 10 words, answer was just confirming the substitution already made in the original post...